# Upper bounding a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

So I have the following problem.

> Let $F$ be the set of functions for which $|f(x)| \le 2$  for all $x$ and $\int\limits_{0}^{5} [f(x)]^2dx \le 16$. Over all the functions in $F$, compute the maximum value of $\int\limits_{0}^{5} xf(x)dx$.

My first intention to solve problem was to use the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.

Therefore, if we let:

$$I = \int\limits_{0}^{5} xf(x)dx$$

We can then say that:

$$I^2 = \left[\int\limits_{0}^{5} xf(x)dx\right]^2$$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we have that:

$$I^2 = \left[\int\limits_{0}^{5} xf(x)dx\right]^2 \le \int\limits_{0}^{5} x^2dx * \int\limits_{0}^{5} [f(x)]^2dx$$

We want the maximum value, so I let $\int\limits_{0}^{5} [f(x)]^2dx = 16$:

$$I^2 = \left[\int\limits_{0}^{5} xf(x)dx\right]^2 \le \left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{0}^{5} * 16$$
$$I^2 = \left[\int\limits_{0}^{5} xf(x)dx\right]^2 \le \frac{125}{3} * 16 = \frac{125*16}{3}$$

Therefore, I got $I$ to be:

$$I = \frac{20\sqrt{15}}{3}$$

However, the answer provided by the solution was $24$.

Was there an error in my calculations? I have an inkling that the first statement where $|f(x) \le 2|$ might be the reason that I cannot use the inequality, but I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have only shown that the maximum value is at most $20\sqrt{15}/3$; whether this value can actually be attainable by a function in $F$ is another matter.

Comment: @angryavian it is actually $20\sqrt{5}/3 \approx 14.9 < 24$, so must have a bug

Comment: @angryavian i see. Is there another way to find the maximum value of the integral then?

Comment: @gt6989b it's $\sqrt{15}$, not $\sqrt{5}$

Comment: Must be, you didn't use the bound on $f$ at all

Comment: @angryavian you're right

Comment: I got an upper bound of $25$ using $\int xf(x)\,{\rm d}x \leq \int |xf(x)|\,{\rm d}x$, but I didn't use the bound on the integral. We must use everything..

Comment: if you just bound $f \leq 2$ then you get $$\int_0^5 2x = 25$$ which is better than your bound slightly, but still not good enough for $24$

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll find another method to solve the problem then

Comment: The function $f$ that takes the value $2$ on the interval $[1,5]$ and is zero elsewhere seems to give the value of $24$, but I am not sure how to show that you can't do any better.

Comment: This function doesn't satisfy $\int_0^5 f^2 \leq 16$.

Comment: @IvoTerek it does, it's zero over $[0,1]$

Comment: Oh, my bad. You're right.

Comment: @angryavian You have the correct $f$.

Comment: @Martin R 3 Yes, of course! I think it's much better and if I see your $\int_{0}^5f(x)dx$ so It annoys me. I am sorry.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Well, I disagree :) See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83545/int-with-limits-or-without. Perhaps such cosmetic decisions should be left to the author instead of editing a bunch of old postings.

Comment: @Martin R OK! We'll left to the author.